# Encrypting a stream with ChaCha20Poly1305

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I was wondering, how should I encrypt a lot of data using `ChaCha20Poly1305` or `AesGcm`. My project is running **.NET 7**.

I need to encrypt a data from 100 MB to 1 GB using one of these algorithms (ChaCha20Poly1305 is a better option for me). I don't want to load all the data into the memory.

I'm asking, because I don't see any method overload for ChaCha20Poly1305.Encrypt and Decrypt, which will take data from a stream and writes the encrypted data to the stream.

I know I can use a libraries, like NaCl, Libsodium or BouncyCastle, but I'm asking because I would like to do it without using any external libraries. Don't suggest me using classes like Aes, I want to use one of the above.

---

The function I was expecting to be available, that it isn't.

```cs
// Other code like key generation ^
byte[] nonce = new byte[12];
byte[] tag = new byte[16];

var cipher = new ChaCha20Poly1305(key);

using FileStream inputFile = File.OpenRead("plainTextFile.dat");
using FileStream outputFile = File.OpenWrite("encrypted.bin");

// Error CS1503: Cannot convert System.IO.FileStream to byte[]
cipher.Encrypt(nonce, inputFile, outputFile, tag);
```

Thanks for any help. I tried ChatGPT, but no success. A code snippet or approach how to do it would be useful (I'm not very good at crypto things, so code snippet should be better).

Comment: Use a binary stream for writing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.common.binarystream.write?view=sc-sm-dotnet-2016#microsoft-enterprisemanagement-common-binarystream-write(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)

Comment: That's intentionally the case. Most of these *authenticated* encryption APIs will not return any cipher/plaintext until the authentication tag has been calculated/verified. This is especially true for decryption more than encryption. Authentication encryption is meant for data that can be stored entirely in memory. The fact that it's authenticated encryption is signified by the GCM and Poly1305 labels.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk so this means that I should use ChaCha20Poly1305 only for smaller messages and data? So then, for current case, where are large files, I should use encryption algorithm like AesCbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These algorithms are of a style called an AEAD, which stands for *authenticated encryption with associated data*.  They have a nice security property that they provide both privacy and integrity, but it's not secure to release any plaintext until the tag (which is at the end) has been verified.

Thus, what you need to do is encrypt your data in chunks, each one with a separate nonce.  The easiest way to do this is with a fixed-size chunk, like 64 KiB (65536 bytes), although the last chunk can be smaller.  Each chunk gets a 64-bit index, starting at zero.  You XOR the chunk index with the original nonce, and use that value as the nonce to encrypt your chunk.  When you encrypt that data, you'll pass that index plus a single byte (1 if it's the last chunk, 0 if not) as the additional data to prevent an attacker from reordering your message, and when you write each chunk, you'll write the encrypted data plus the tag.

When you decrypt, it's the same thing.  You XOR the chunk index with the original nonce to get the nonce for that chunk and pass the index and single byte as the additional data.  Note that when you read from the file, you'll be reading 64 KiB of data plus 16 bytes of tag in each chunk.

You certainly can use AES-CBC for encrypting data, but if you don't use a separate MAC, such as HMAC with a secure hash function (e.g., HMAC-SHA-256), then you're allowing an attacker to tamper with your data, which isn't secure.  Since you must verify the MAC before releasing the plaintext to avoid security problems, you're going to run into the same problem as with an AEAD.  In fact, an AEAD is just a standard encryption algorithm with a MAC built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the cipher class but it seems to expect a byte array and not a file, so just read the file into an array and pass it into the function,
now write a new file with the encripted array:

```
using System.IO;


byte[] fileAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("plainTextFile.dat");
byte[] fileAsBytesButEncypted;
cipher.Encrypt(nonce, fileAsBytes, fileAsBytesButEncypted, tag);
File.WriteAllBytes("encrypted.bin", fileAsBytesButEncypted);
```

Comment: That's the problem - I cannot load the entire file into a memory as the file is too large. Maybe encrypting it in a chunks, but then I don't know if the tag would work properly when encrypted in chunks. The 'cipher' class is not a class, but an instance of a class if I understood your answer.